# Mostrar nombre de mes en dropdownlist en ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hola amigos estoy haciendo una aplicación donde tengo 3 dropdownlist en cascada mi problema es que quiero mostrar el nombre del mes en mi dropdownlist y no el numero cuando mando a traer mi procedimiento almacenado. Estoy usando Asp.net c#. Les muestro mi código espero puedan ayudarme Gracias.

Capa Datos

```
    public DataTable Mes(int id_Pais, int Año)
    {
        SqlParameter[] sqlparameter =  
        { 
            new SqlParameter("@Id_Pais", SqlDbType.Int),
            new SqlParameter("@Año", SqlDbType.Int)                
        };

        sqlparameter[0].Value = id_Pais;
        sqlparameter[1].Value = Año;

        return _conexion.ExecuteDataTable("mes",sqlparameter); 
    }
```

este es mi primero código donde solo llamo a mi procedimiento "mes" y le paso los parametros.

Capa de Negocio

```
 public DataTable Listar_Mes(int id_Pais, int Año)
    {
        return conexion.Mes(id_Pais,Año);       
    }
```

Capa Presentacion

```
int id_Pais = Convert.ToInt32(this.ddlPais.SelectedValue);
            int Año = Convert.ToInt32(this.ddlAño.SelectedValue);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = t.Mes(id_Pais, Año);
            ddlMes.DataSource = dt;
            ddlMes.DataTextField= "".ToString(); //Aqui es donde quiero mostrar los nombres de los meses y no el numero
            ddlMes.DataValueField = "mes".ToString();
            ddlMes.DataBind();
```

Este es el resultado de mi interfaz [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el resultado de mi procedimiento almacenado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes editar el store procedure para que te regrese un nombre de columna ?. Si podes editarlo pudes usar `ddlMes.DataTextField= "NombreAsignado"`

Comment: Hola Benjamín que tal así es pero des afortunadamente no puedo editarlo hay alguna forma en que pueda hacerlo o alguna expresión lambda que me permita hacer eso de antemano gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Lo primero es ponerle un alias en el segundo campo **"descripcion"** de tu procedimiento donde obtienes los datos, luego en ddlMes.DataTextField= "NombreAsignado" , aquí debes de poner el alias de tu store.

Comment: @SHINOBI Se me ocurre que podrias intentar editat el objeto `DataTable` despues de llamar al metodo `Mes` despues   `dt = t.Mes(id_Pais, Año);   dt.Columns[1].ColumnName = "Mes";` . la idea es agregarle un nombre la columna del DataTable

Comment: @Benjamin Camacho Excelente compañero también funciona esta solución y estas en lo correcto lo ideal seria asignarle un nombre a la columna muchas gracias por tu ayuda..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recomendaria que inspecciones el datatable cuando este retorna una respuesta evaluando que nombre le asigna a este campo sin alias en el procedure

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces al detenerse la ejecucion en el breakpoint usa la lupa que se visualiza al inspeccionar la variable y alli obtendras la estructura del datatable pudiendo observar que nombre la asigna a esa columna

El nombre que le asigne lo usaras en `DataTextField`

Comment: Gracias Leandro le hice como postulaste y efectivamente le asigno un nombre llamado "Column1" Gracias por tu ayuda.